# I'm trying to update and keep value SQL PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to make if the selected column is empty, the value will be keep to the previous value when it updated. Sorry I am just a newbie. Thank you for your help.

```
// No file was selected for upload, your (re)action goes here
    if($_FILES['photo']['size'] == 0)  { 
        $newfilename = {$sql = "SELECT photo FROM employees WHERE id=?";}
    }

$sql = "UPDATE employees SET name=?, address=?, salary=?, photo=? WHERE id=?";

    if( $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql) ){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssi", $param_name, $param_address, $param_salary, $newfilename , $param_id);
    }
```

Comment: add more logic, which dynamically builds your query.

Comment: Your code is incomplete / has errors.  The second `if` statement does not have a matching closing `}`, and your `$newfilename =...` does not need `{` around the assignment (`{$sql = ....}` should just be `$sql = ....`)

Comment: ya, i know there was an error. I just trying to make like that. can u give me example ? @cale_b

Comment: can u give me example ? @LawrenceCherone

Comment: Added a closing "}" for "if"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thx for the help guys, i have my own answer.
i'm just adding session function which save the previous value

```
if($_FILES['photo']['size'] == 0)  { 
    $newfilename = {$sql = "SELECT photo FROM employees WHERE id=?";}
}
```

to

```
if($_FILES['photo']['size'] == 0) 
    {   
        $newfilename = $_SESSION['photo'];
    }
```